# Can't update products qty in cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, upgrade, qty

I have some trouble with updating products quantity in cart. When I change qty in the mini cart and click update, nothing happened.

I saw a similar problem in Magento 1.9 and there were answers to add something to the `cart.phtml`, adding some form-id etc. But I have that in `updatecart.phtml` and it doesn't fix my problem in Magento 2.

Here is HTML of update button.
[image: Here is HTML of update button.]

Here is issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6656